# Android Studio button crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, button

Good day, ma'am/sir. I would like to ask how to fix this crash thing in **Android Studio** on my **Bluestacks** emulator; the problem is the **button**, every time I click it the application automatically closes. How do I fix this? Below is the image. Thank you in advance.

[app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkrZs.png)

[after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWcH9.png)

Code snippet

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Knb3.png)
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9djm.png)

[Register page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BdEo.png)
[Register page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRi99.png)

[After signing in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4MOX.png)

[AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86TBO.png)

Comment: please add your activity and layout code in your question to check an error.

Comment: To have a chance of a meaningful advice you must include the code. Currently, without any code, the question does not fulfill the StackOverflow requirements, I believe.

Comment: Please post your code for better help.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I already updated it and added the code.

Comment: @webenthusiast don't add screenshots of the code. Add direct code into your question not its screenshots.

Comment: Forgive me for being naive, it's my first time here in SO seeking help so I'm kind of not used to it. However, it's fine now, I already found a solution for my code. Thank you. :D